# Long Web API route attributes divide by zero error

Tags: android, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an android application whereby I am using web api to send and receive json data from a server. One of my queries include up to 30 parameter in the route attribute as you can see below. As a result I am getting a Attempt to divide by zero error. The error line is **GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf Register)** I have increased maxURLlength, maxQueryStringLength, and maxRequestLength in the web.condfig file, but nothing worked.

**Question:** What would caused this issue? Every out actions with their specific routes attributes works in the controller.

**Attempted to divide by zero.**
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.

```
<Route("api/dtl/GetResults/{1}/{30})>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer that I was looking. Long routes are not permitted that is why I get the Cannot divide by zero error. I was doing things all wrong. All I needed to do was correctly configure my route in the form of

```
<Route("api/DTL/ActionName")>
```

Instead of

```
<Route("api/dtl/ActionName/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{Zip}")>
```

Then I can just call this action via a url like so

http://localhost:17895/api/dtl/PostCreateMember?Username=jason&Gender=Male, etc, etc.

So the url can be as long as it wants as long as I have defined the model to accept it. You can learn more at https://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/01/20/restful-api-with-aspnet50.html

Answer (score 0):

Having URL parameters in a POST method in not usually a problem, however when you have too many that can create an issue as you've already seen.

A better idea is to pass everything you need in the body of your request. You could create an object containing everything you need, chuck it in the body of the request, have a model representing it in your API and then your POST request becomes much easier and simpler to work with.

One more thing, URL parameters need to be URL encoded as your data can have special characters like ampersand, stuff like that can completely screw up your URLs and you might start seeing 404 errors as your routes no longer match.